# Binding a DataSet to Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, adapter

I want to bind the results of an SQL query to a Listbox of an WPF interface. As many examples I have seen, I cannot tweak my application, so as to work properly. I use this code behind:

```
string sqlStr1 = "SELECT Players.LastName FROM Players";

SqlDataAdapter dAdapt1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr1, cnStr);
DataSet dataSet1 = new DataSet();
dAdapt1.Fill(dataSet1);

List1.DataContext = dataSet1;
```

and in the xaml page:

```
<ListBox Name="List1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ></ListBox>
```

What is the way to bind them so as the name to appear in the Listbox?

Without adding any Binding in the xaml page, it throws an exceprtion when I try to run it. What is wrong?

Comment: If you have an exception **post it**.

Comment: It is an XamlParseException with a message "The invocation of the constructor on type 'TennisPlayers.PlayersHome' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '7'." Furthermore it opens a new page with a header "No Source available".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your itemssource is not set.

you can do:

```
 List1.ItemsSource= dataSet1.Tables["Players"]; //instead of List1.DataContext = dataSet1;
```

or

```
 List1.DataContext = dataSet1.Tables["Players"];
 <ListBox Name="List1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

the LastName is assumed as the Columnname. btw all code is just handwritten, so there may be some errors :)

Comment: btw instead of set the source to the dataset you should set the source to the datatable in your dataset

Comment: Wanted to answer the same, but you were just a bit more early :).

Comment: The second way you suggest I had already tried but I still receive the same exception. The first is not acceptable as message states "cannot implicitly covert from Dataset to IEnumerable". What can cause the XamlParseException?

Comment: the you have to set the Datatable. see my edit. i assume that the datablename is "Players"

Comment: The problem with the excpeption is over, as it was derived from an error in the connection. The Listbox works now but the data appears as System.Data.DataRowView. Which property should I override in order to appear correctly? I think ToString() is not what I search in this occasion.

Comment: as long as you define no datatemplate its ok to see it. i will edit my post to show the datatemplate. btw if you use a datagrid with autogeneratcolumns=true you should see your data.